# How to copy forum structure Advanced Forum?

Tags: nodes

I wish to use the Forum or Advanced forum module to create forums. But to save time I need to duplicate forum structure to create new ones. I've done Google search but did not find any useful information.

For example for a schools website, I can create another school just by copying a school structure that'll copy all child forums as classes which I'll not need to recreate.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What you mean by forum structure?

Comment: Copying the Forum along with Child forums with/without posts within them.

Comment: I am not sure whether it works or not. Can you try http://drupal.org/project/node_export

Comment: Forum is not listed - moreover a forum structure will contain plenty of nodes.

Comment: I am also waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is something like an Install Profile: https://drupal.org/developing/distributions

You can create Install Profiles from exiting sites with:
https://drupal.org/project/profiler
https://drupal.org/project/profiler_builder

What I would do is make the first site exactly how you want it and then turn that into a Install Profile.

An easier way to do this if you have AEgir is to just clone your first site and then keep it as a template to clone others.